# Annotate() is returning duplicates in response

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**I am trying to Order all `DropTemplate` belonging to an `Author` by the `start_time` @property or `visible_start_time` on the `CollectionTemplates` related to the `DropTemplate`.**

I have the following models:

```
class DropTemplate(TimeStampedModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    @property
    def earliest_start_time(self) -> Union[None, str]:
        earliest_collection = (
            self.collectiontemplates.filter(drop_template_id=self.id, visible_start_time__isnull=False)
            .only("visible_start_time")
            .order_by("visible_start_time")
            .first()
        )
        if earliest_collection is None:
            return None
        else:
            return earliest_collection.visible_start_time
```

```
class CollectionTemplate(TimeStampedModel):
    drop_template = models.ForeignKey(
        DropTemplate, related_name="collectiontemplates", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    visible_start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And the following Django Rest Framework `ModelViewSet`:

```
class DropTemplateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DropTemplateSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ["start_time"]
    ordering = ["start_time"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return DropTemplate.objects.annotate(start_time=F("collectiontemplates__visible_start_time")).filter(author__id=self.kwargs["author_pk"])
```

My problem now is that I am returning duplicate values with this Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
DropTemplate.objects.annotate(start_time=Subquery(collection_templates.values("visible_start_time")[:1])).filter(publisher__id=self.kwargs[author_pk"])
```

was the solution